# Incomplete gmail proxy URL in email open tracking via 1x1 image way

Tags: email, proxy, gmail, tracking

My tracking URL after sending the mail in Gmail looks like this

```
<img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/M0eT59-eQFXoo_sSnCIg9Xye-ZXIwyMulKSFO-m_i0PvlwtKsLn5WYr9Nqxq25TDGhOhnGCUeA8d0r4fCZtZ61V1fR-dEtgHO7E8SoJ2FMjs86GLYtlueZ75C4cxoQogEIsqfg=s0-d-e1-ft#http://xyz.abc.com:9099/MailMongo/trackmail/5b8cc4d738770a701aa1709b" alt="" class="CToWUd">
```

But gmail is sending 2 server requests like `https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/M0eT59-eQFXoo_sSnCIg9Xye-ZXIwyMulKSFO-m_i0PvlwtKsLn5WYr9Nqxq25TDGhOhnGCUeA8d0r4fCZtZ61V1fR-dEtgHO7E8SoJ2FMjs86GLYtlueZ75C4cxoQogEIsqfg=s0-d-e1-ft`which return 404.

Why is it removing my tracker URL in network request? Help Pls.

My real tracker URL is like http://xyz.abc.com:9099/MailMongo/trackmail/5b8cc4d738770a701aa1709b. I can convert it into something like http://xyz.abc.com/trackmail?id=5b8cc4d738770a701aa1709b if custom port is an issue.